# Code Coverage is Showing as 95%...But it still throws an Error

Tags: unit-test, case-object

I have a requirement where i need to create a VF page ,Apex controller and test class.But when i run the test class ,the code coverage is showing as 95% ,where one method executes and the other it throws an Error as :

Error Message :

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 5004B000000roMzQAI; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, SendEscalationMail: execution of BeforeUpdate
>
> caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>
> Trigger.SendEscalationMail: line 358, column 1: []
>
> Stack Trace :
>
> Class.MassCaseClose.save: line 26, column 1
>       Class.MassCaseCloseTest.TestMassCaseClose: line 25, column 1

Controller :

```
public with sharing class MassCaseClose {

      public Case objCase {get;set;} 
      private List<Case> lstCase; 
      public MassCaseClose() 
      { 
           objCase = new Case(); 
           lstCase = new List<Case>(); 
           String strRecordIds = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ids');
            set<Id> setCaseIds = new set<Id>();
            for(String strid : strRecordIds.split(','))
            {
                setCaseIds.add(id.valueof(strid.trim()));
            }
            lstCase = [SELECT Id, Status FROM Case WHERE Id IN: setCaseIds];
     } 
     public PageReference save() 
   { 
      for(Case objCaseRecord: lstCase) 
    { 
      objCaseRecord.Status = objCase.Status; 
      objCaseRecord.Closer_Comment__c=objCase.Closer_Comment__c;
       } 
      update lstCase; 
      return new pagereference('/500'); 

   } 
     public PageReference cancel() 
    { 
      return new pagereference('/500'); 
  } 

}
```

Test Class :

```
@isTest
public class MassCaseCloseTest{
    public static TestMethod void TestMassCaseClose(){

       Account a = new Account();
        a.Name ='TestAccount';        
        insert a;

        Contact c = new Contact();
        c.FirstName ='Test';
        c.LastName ='Contact';
        insert c;

        Case cas = new Case();
        cas.Status='Closed';
        cas.Closer_Comment__c='Testing for the Mass closer of Cases';
        insert cas;   

        Test.startTest();
        ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('ids',cas.id);
        MassCaseClose objCase = new MassCaseClose ();
        /*objCase.Status = 'Closed';
        objCase.Closer_Comment__c='Testing for the Mass closer of Cases';*/
        objCase.save();
        Test.stopTest();
    }   
     public static TestMethod void TestMassCaseClose1(){

       Account a = new Account();
        a.Name ='TestAccount';        
        insert a;

        Contact c = new Contact();
        c.FirstName ='Test';
        c.LastName ='Contact';
        insert c;

        Case cas = new Case();
        cas.Status='Closed';
        cas.Closer_Comment__c='Testing for the Mass closer of Cases';
        insert cas;   

        Test.startTest();
        ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('ids',cas.id);
        MassCaseClose objCase = new MassCaseClose ();
        /*objCase.Status = 'Closed';
        objCase.Closer_Comment__c='Testing for the Mass closer of Cases';*/
        objCase.Cancel();
        Test.stopTest();
    }   
   }
```

The Error message where i get is for the Trigger where that line is :

```
 if(!newCase.Status.equals(oldCase.Status)){
```

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: You have to have a look at the trigger `SendEscalationMail`  line number **: line 358**. There is something is being operated on a null object.

Comment: Where is the trigger code ?

Comment: @Monish:The trigger contains around 450 lines and i haven't posted here.

Comment: The issue is in the trigger only. I think it occurring while inserting the case.